# PHP POST validation error removes all entries

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

I am trying to build a form and have run into some difficulty. When the form is posted if there is a validation error all of the entered data is removed! Is there any way to keep the date in the form? I am also trying to send the form data to a page named contact-engine.php
I can send it by changing the form action to action="contact-engine.php" but then my validation does not work! I'm basically stuck and have run out of ideas after several hours of trying to figure this out. Code is as follows:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$addDateErr = $nameErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = $messageErr = $questionErr = "";
    $addDate = $name = $email = $subject = $message = $question = "";

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {

 //Date
   if (empty($_POST["addDate"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["addDate"]);}

 //Name
    if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
    else
    {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
    {
    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
    }

//Email
if (empty($_POST["email"]))
{$emailErr = "Email is required";}
else
{
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
{
$emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}
}

//Subject
if (empty($_POST["subject"]))
{$comment = "";}
else
{$comment = test_input($_POST["subject"]);}

//Message
if (empty($_POST["message"]))
{$messageErr = "A message is required";}
else
{$comment = test_input($_POST["message"]);}

//Question
if (empty($_POST["question"]))
{$comment = "";}
else
{$comment = test_input($_POST["question"]);}

}
function test_input($data)
{
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
}
?>



<form method="post" id="form" action="
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p><br />

<!--Date--><div class="contact-font">
    Date Photography needed (if necessary)<br />
    <input type="text" name="addDate" id="datepicker" size="25" value="
<?php echo $addDate;?>">
    </div>

<!--Name--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
    <span class="asterix">* </span>Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="name" class="border" size="25"><span class="error">
<?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
</div>

<!--Email--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
    <span class="asterix">* </span>Email:<br />
    <input type="text" name="email" class="border" size="25">
<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
</div>

<!--Subject--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
    Subject:<br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" class="border" size="25"<?php echo $subject;?>">
</div>

    <!--Message--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
    <span class="asterix">* </span>Message:<br />
    <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="message" class="border"></textarea>
<span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
</div><br />

<p id="info-req">How did you find about Darren Morton Photography?</p>
<!--Question--><select id="marketing" name="question"<?php echo $question;?>">
    <option value="----------" style="color:black">----------</option>
    <option value="Web Search" style="color:black">Google Search</option>
    <option value="Web Search" style="color:black">Social Media</option>
    <option value="Word of mouth" style="color:black">Word of mouth</option>
    <option value="Other" style="color:black">Other</option>
</select><br /><br />

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You simply fill in your form with POSTed information. That's called a "sticky" form. You can also use the SESSION variable if you want to remember the data even if the user leaves the page and comes back. e.g. $_SESSION['POSTED'] = $_POST; Then use code like Panama Jack's but instead check `$_SESSION['POSTED']['addDate']` with isset and fill in the form with it if it is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this. Leave the from action as you had before not your `contact-engine.php` file.  Then see if the `$_POST` is set and then it will fill the input with the recent value. Example

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="border" size="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) { echo $_POST['name']; } ?>"><span class="error">
<?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
```

Then you can do that for your other inputs.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you very much for your help Panama Jack.

Comment: No problem, you can implement the small code adjustment above to keep your forms from removing the entries in the mean time until you implement your sessions, which can give you time to work it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sessions for both problems. Just google for it.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul. I have found some session pages on the w3 site that I will check out. I do remember learning about sessions when I did my training but my memory is vague!